# Biblatex, compiling the whole bibliography with \nocite and marking used entries of the document

Tags: biblatex

I have a large bibliography file. In my paper I dont use all entries from my biblatex bibliography. When I use  `\printbibliography` and `\nocite{*}`, is it possible to attach the bolded word "gelesen" in the output to every entry that is cited in the paper, while the non-cited entries go without any further specification?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`biblatex` has the option `citetracker`, i.e.,

```
\usepackage[citetracker]{biblatex}
```

Then you can use the command `\ifciteseen`.

A possibility would be

```
\renewbibmacro{finentry}{%
  \finentry
  \ifciteseen{\addspace Gelesen.}{}%
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use `hyperref` with the `pagebackref` option, or the `citeref` package, which does approximately the same. Then each reference entry gets a list of page numbers, where this entry has been cited. No page numbers => not cited.